# Parse Query find method returns object not array

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I am working with a mobile App which uses Parse as a backend and I have an issue with the find function. When running the find function in the format of:

```
var = firstQuery = (new Parse.Query("MyParseObject"))
  .find(),
  secondQuery = (new Parse.Query("OtherParseObject")).get(id)

// there is only one object that firstQuery can find
Parse.Promise.when(firstQuery, secondQuery)
  .then( function (query1res, query2res) {
    // query1res should return only one result wrapped in an array,
    // instead query1res is an object without a get method

   query1res.forEach (function (res) {
     // this fails: cannot get .length of undefined
   })  
   // ... do stuff with the returned data


  })
```

Is there something i am missing? I am sure this used to work before, but now it does not.

It is quite difficult to correctly get in an debug this issue thanks to the way Parse works, but their docs outline that this should return an array, but it does not at this point of time.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-parallel), it looks like `Parse.Promise.when` expects an array, although based on [this support thread](https://www.parse.com/questions/parallel-promises-with-parsepromisewhen), the results will be passed in as individual arguments to the `then` handler. Give this a try:

```
Parse.Promise.when([firstQuery, secondQuery])
.then(function (query1res, query2res) {

   // use query1res and query2res
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was down to a function deeper in the code, which needed to return a promise to chain off of. after adding this the code was happy enough. The function that needed to return the promise was called in the forEach and has nothing to do with the initial two queries, which is what was throwing me.